# AWS SQS SendMessage Auth Signature Version 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, digital-signature, amazon-sqs

I've been going crazy over this for hours. I'm trying to use the SendMessage API call to the Amazon SQS message queue.

I'm following the Signature Version 2 method (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html)

I receive the error for a non matching signature. I've been thinking it has to do with the lexicographic byte ordering but I've spent hours trying to figure it out and had no luck :-/

I can send a message successfully with this as my "query string components":
"AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIEXAMPLE&Action=SendMessage&Expires=2013-02-22T12%3A19%3A30&MessageBody=12321&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Version=2012-11-05"

broken down as these name value pairs for easy reading:

["AWSAccessKeyId", "Action", "Expires", "MessageBody", "SignatureMethod", "SignatureVersion", "Version"]

["AKIAIEXAMPLE", "SendMessage", "2013-02-22T12%3A19%3A30", "12321", "HmacSHA256", "2", "2012-11-05"]

But NOT with this set of query string components:

"AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIEXAMPLE&Action=SendMessage&Expires=2013-02-22T12%3A19%3A30&MessageBody=234&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Version=2012-11-05"

broken down as:

["AWSAccessKeyId", "Action", "Expires", "MessageBody", "SignatureMethod", "SignatureVersion", "Version"]

["AKIAIEXAMPLE", "SendMessage", "2013-02-22T12%3A19%3A30", "234", "HmacSHA256", "2", "2012-11-05"]

The only difference between the two is the MessageBody's value (12321 works, 234 doesn't) and I've tried a variety of values, both using characters and integers and can't seem to put my finger on the problem.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What language/platform are you using? I'd highly recommend using the appropriate [AWS SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/tools/) for your language/platform of choice to interact with the AWS API, if at all possible, insofar these do all the heavy lifting for you (and then some ...), esp. this purely protocol related stuff.

Comment: I don't mean to ask something obvious, but did you calculate the signature using the first request, then just change the message value in the second request?   If so, you need to calculate the signature separately.

Comment: Nope, individual signatures for each message since it's part of the signature. 

And using R on Mac OSX. I don't believe they have an SDK for R, although if I'm wrong that would be awesome

Comment: Are you URL-encoding the message body?  If you are using GET and query parameters, you have to make sure it is properly encoded.  Although, I'm not sure why 234 wouldn't work.  I don't think that requires any encoding.

Comment: Yea, I was URL-encoding the message body and was trying my best to properly encode it although it never ended up working. I could retrieve messages no problem and put some messages but ended up giving it up. Amount of time was finally just not worth it :-/